# tkinter: how do i make the Scrollbar react to the new size of the frame

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, scrollbar

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class Scrollbar:
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = ttk.Frame(master)
        frame.pack()
        self.canvas = Canvas(frame, width=700, height=930)
        self.scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(frame, orient=VERTICAL, command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.main_frame = ttk.Frame(self.canvas)
        self.placing_widgets()

    def placing_widgets(self):
        self.canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
        self.scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)
        self.canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox('all')))
        self.canvas.create_window((0,0), window=self.main_frame, anchor='n')
        Frame1(self.main_frame)
        
class Frame1:
    def __init__(self, main_frame):
        self.main_frame = main_frame
        for i in range(100):
            self.button = ttk.Button(self.main_frame, text=f"Button {i}", command=lambda i=i: self.destroying(i))
            self.button.grid(row=i, column=0, pady=5)

    def destroying(self, i):
        for frame in self.main_frame.winfo_children():
            frame.destroy()
        Frame2(self.main_frame)

class Frame2:
    def __init__(self, main_frame):
        self.main_frame = main_frame
        self.button = ttk.Button(self.main_frame, text='back', command=self.destroying)
        self.button.pack()

    def destroying(self):
        for frame in self.main_frame.winfo_children():
            frame.destroy()
        Frame1(self.main_frame)

def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.config(background='black')
    Scrollbar(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I couldn't find a solution to this problem anywhere on the internet.

I have given a scrollbar to a lengthy frame but when I make the frame shorter, I don't know why the scrollbar doesn't resize to the frame's length.

Above is a short program that represents the problem I am talking about. The program has 2 different pages, one with 100 buttons and the other with one button. You can switch between pages with any buttons and see that the page with one button is scrollable which shouldn't be.

Could you please provide a solution to how I could make the scrollbar resize to the frame's length? Thank you for your time.

Comment: You need to bind `<Configure>` on `self.main_frame`, not `self.canvas`.

Comment: Easy. It worked! Thank you very much.